# Analyse the packets from server to my machine

Tags: browser, browser-addons

I recently read NS2, which is used to simulate the networks. Now I want to see how my packets are sent to the server and received from the server. Though I can make use of ping command, I want a **browser** specific application, that allows me to *visualize* it.

Where I can *see* how the packets are sent from one node to the other node, as NS2 NAM does.

Is there any application that is able to do this? Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application uses the HTTP protocol, then you may use the [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/):

> Charles is an HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor / Reverse Proxy that enables a developer to view all of the HTTP and SSL / HTTPS traffic between their machine and the Internet. This includes requests, responses and the HTTP headers (which contain the cookies and caching information).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for but you can maybe try Fiddler at http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ , it lets you log all the HTTP traffic between your computer and the internet.